# How to specify include paths for a UEFI application built using an INF file in edk2?

Tags: uefi, inf, edk2

The INF file format is being used to specify module information for UEFI application. Source files are mentioned using [Sources] section. The include path where the header required by these files are automatically generated giving no control over it.

In my use case I want to explicitly specify which Include paths to add, instead of edk2 auto-generated ones.
Can anyone help me where I can mention the include paths explicitly for the module.

I tried adding [Includes] section inside INF file, but edk2 is throwing error and I believe it should not be added in INF. ([https://tianocore-docs.github.io/edk2-InfSpecification/draft/2_inf_overview/28_[includes]_section.html#28-includes-section](https://tianocore-docs.github.io/edk2-InfSpecification/draft/2_inf_overview/28_%5Bincludes%5D_section.html#28-includes-section))

Since I don't want other Libs that are built by DEC or DSC file affected if I had [Includes] sections in DEC/DSC file.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You're asking how to work around the build system instead of how to work *with* the build system. Could you explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: The problem is the build system creates Include paths which are not required by the module, And there are two include paths which have header with same names (say one is 32bit and other for 64bit) and this is causing problems when wrong definitions are fixed.

Comment: I think the question would be better rewritten as stating what you are trying to do, with a minimal reproducible example, what commands you use to build, and what errors you are encountering during your attempt.